# What is v the line position in the sensor plane in pixels?

Tags: stereoscopy

[image: imagediagram]

What is v = vr = vl?

Why do I want to maximize v for nearby objects assuming those sensor planes are 640(W) * 480(H) resolution in pixels?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Can you give a little more explanation - maybe also show what you've tried so far. Oh, also mention what you're actually trying to do/solve here please

Comment: The URL of the page where you got this could help.

Comment: I believe this is a portion of a homework assignment for a 3rd-year computer science class, about automotive machine vision ([Course Hero link, partially visible](https://www.coursehero.com/file/56770137/CS7639-O01-HW4pdf/)). Without context to the rest of the text in the homework assignment, and based on being about stereoscopic machine vision, I'm closing this question as "Needs detail or clarity" until more context is posted (with the possibility that it could be closed/reclosed as "off-topic to Photo-SE").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is depth of focus at the image plane, because w/o that you cannot really create a 3D stereoscopic reproduction from the images. And it relates to the recording of Zmin-Zmax in the original scene.

Achieving adequate depth of focus is more difficult at shorter subject distances and higher magnifications... I don't think it means to maximize the depth of focus relative to longer distances; only relative to what is easily/readily achieved at the shorter distance.

The depth of focus can be manipulated and tilted by tilting the image plane relative to the scene (see tilt shift lens use). That increases the depth of focus into the scene (with other costs). This also seems to be indicated by the drawing.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with depth of focus _per se_. This is about stereoscopic machine-vision, in this example in automotive machine vision.